# Mysql get sum of float field in hours

Tags: mysql

I have a database table that contains some fields, one of these fields is a mysql **float type field**.

in this field I keep how long I was on a bike ride in hours for example

> 2.3   &    3.3    &    2 = 8 hours
>
> 2.55   &   2.25   &    1 = 6.20 Hours

any ideas how I can get the desired total time?

Thanks

Comment: So, you want to round the sum to the nearest int?

Comment: Change the data type to DECIMAL

Comment: Example added in question

Comment: @Er.KT, why this `2.55 & 2.25 & 1 ` should be equal to `6.20`, but not `5.8` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest read the values as hours and minutes, so 2.55 is 2 hours and 55 minutes, 2.25 is 2 hours and 25 minutes, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The solution would be to change the type of your column to `TIME`, don't keep it like this. you will only make it more difficult for yourself if you keep building on a database which isn't set up decent.

If you change it to a `TIME` column you can just easily do a SUM and it will calculate it correctly

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the [Sum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) method perhaps?

```
SELECT SUM(yourColumn) FROM yourTable
```

or you meant to [Round](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) instead?

```
SELECT Round(SUM(yourColumn)) FROM yourTable
```

**UPDATE**
You could use this query, certainly not the most elegant, but produces the result you described. I also not universal, as it depends on the delimeter character.

```
SELECT
    SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(subQuery.HourPart * 60 * 60 + subQuery.MinutePart * 60)) as Result
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            CASE
                WHEN CONVERT(yourColumn, char) LIKE '%.%' THEN 
                    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(yourColumn, '.', 1) as unsigned) 
                ELSE 
                    yourColumn
            END as HourPart
           ,CASE
                WHEN CONVERT(yourColumn, char) LIKE '%.%' THEN 
                    CASE    
                        WHEN CONVERT(TimeInHours, char) LIKE '%._' THEN 
                            CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(TimeInHours, '.', -1) * 10 as unsigned) 
                        ELSE 
                            CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(TimeInHours, '.', -1) as unsigned) 
                    END
                ELSE 0
            END as MinutePart
        FROM 
            yourTable
    ) as subQuery
```

Comment: Round wont work in my case, please see the example I have added in question

Answer (score 0):

Complex solution using Mysql *"User-Defined Variables"*, `CEIL`, `FLOOR`, `MOD` functions and `IF` operator. I've created test table `duration` which has the field named `duration`(same as test table).
 It has type `FLOAT` and two sequences of values: 1) `2.3 | 3.3 | 2` , 2) `2.55 | 2.25 | 1`.

```
SET @hours_total := (SELECT sum(duration) FROM `duration`),
    @hours_main := 0.00, @minutes_total := 0.00,
    @hours_rest := 0.00, @minutes_rest := 0.00, @minutes_adjusted := 0.00;

SELECT truncate(hours_main + hours_rest + minutes_adjusted, 2) as result 
FROM (
    SELECT @hours_main := floor(@hours_total) as hours_main,
        @minutes_total := (mod(@hours_total, 1)*100)/60 as minutes_total,  -- converted into hours with minutes residue
        @hours_rest := floor(@minutes_total) as hours_rest,
        @minutes_rest := ceil(60 * mod(@minutes_total, 1)) as minutes_rest,
        @minutes_adjusted := IF(@minutes_rest = 60, 1, @minutes_rest/100) as minutes_adjusted 
    ) as calc
```

The output for the first sequence (`2.3 | 3.3 | 2`) is shown below:

[image]

The output for the second sequence (`2.55 | 2.25 | 1`) is like the following:

[image]